# EXEC sp_spaceused for data monitoring

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am running below SP_spaceused to monitor data of tbl_testrecord table. I am inserting data on this table daily.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused tbl_testrecord;
```

and I am getting result as below:

[image]

The reserved space keeps changing. As per my understanding it should be constant of the table. Please help me to understand why it is changing? Who is changing this and on what basis? And can I modify the reserved space for the table?
Your help is appreciated
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved space is the sum of data + index_size + unused. It will increase while you keep adding data, it is not constant.
You can't modify this space without making changes on data, index...

Take a look at [this page, where it is explained](http://sqlserverzest.com/2013/06/28/sql-server-understanding-sp_spaceused-results-for-database-size-information/).